# getaddrinfo returns information whereas ping.exe says ip is unreachable

Tags: windows, dns, winsock2, getaddrinfo

I work on a problem where I want to avoid a system to launch a connection retry when the target ip is not reachable. (The target ip can be on and off at different times in the day).

I can see that `ping.exe` returns correctly that host is unreachable.

However, in my code, calling `getaddrinfo` succeeds for the same ip address, and I **suspect** it only queries the dns cache.

Is there a way to force `getaddrinfo` not to use dns cache, or another function that would bypass the dns cache ?

Comment: Even if the DNS cache were bypassed, a request to the main DNS system can still return valid information for a machine that is currently down.  DNS simply tells you where a Host is located, not what its current state is.  You are best off NOT trying to avoid the reconnect. Let it fail if the machine is down, and handle the error as needed. Let DNS do its job, let the socket fail and tell you why. Besides, pings are not 100% reliable, as routers/firewalls can be configured to drop ping requests as a security measure.

Comment: I have happened to have a successful results using `IcmpSendEcho()`, it seems to bypass dns cache, do you maintain your advice against using `IcmpSendEcho` instead of `getaddrinfo` so as to know if an ip address is reachable ?

Comment: `IcmpSendEcho()` does not let you specify a hostname, only an IP, so it does not involve DNS at all. `getaddrinfo()` uses DNS (amongst other things) to resolve an IP if you specify a hostname. But neither `getaddrinfo()` nor DNS can tell you if the IP is reachable. I stand by my earlier comment. **DO NOT** try to test for *reachability*. ICMP may report false results depending on network config. The IP might be *reachable* but a given port on it might not be *listening*. The most accurate option is to just attempt the actual connection and handle any error it may report.